# UiTextfield- First letter must be 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am using phone number texfield, now i am using this format for texfield (#) ### ### ###, now issue is that i want first character 0 as compulsary, like this (0) 959 554 545, so user enter whatever first character must be typed 0,

this is my code

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newString = textField.text
    if ((newString == "") && (newString?.count == 0)){
        txtMobileNumber.text = "0"
        return true
    }else if ((newString?.count)! > 0){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method return false if new string count is greater than 15. Else remove `(0)` and empty spaces, then if the string isn't empty add `(0)` at the beginning. Then split the string by every 3 characters and join all string with space separator.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var oldText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if oldText.count > 15 { return false }
    oldText = oldText.replacingOccurrences(of: "(0)", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    if !oldText.isEmpty {
        oldText = "(0)" + oldText
    }
    let newText = String(stride(from: 0, to: oldText.count, by: 3).map {
        let sIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: $0)
        let eIndex = oldText.index(sIndex, offsetBy: 3, limitedBy: oldText.endIndex) ?? oldText.endIndex
        return String(oldText[sIndex..<eIndex])
        }.joined(separator: " "))
    textField.text = newText
    return false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello above answer is working properly for (0) 123 456 789  but what if i want it like (0) 1234 56789

Comment: @GovindRakholiya Do you want to use both formats in same textfield??

Comment: Yes sir, i want both

Comment: @GovindRakholiya One text field can't support both formats at the same time

Comment: so how can i do it with different textfield?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360558/uitextfiled-with-first-letter-must-0-and-format-will-be-like-0-1234-56789 . i have added it @RajeshKumar

Answer (score 2):

In `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method of `UITextFieldDelegate`,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text {
        let str = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).replacingOccurrences(of: "(0)", with: "")
        if !str.isEmpty {
            textField.text = "(0)" + str
        } else {
            textField.text = nil
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Append `(0)` to the newly created `string`, everytime the `textField` is edited.

Comment: its getting crash with this error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Show the code that you've used. Its working fine at my end.

Comment: text formatting is working fine as i am using library for it, i just need first character as 0 not (0).. Here is my code:

Comment: if (textField == txtMobileNumber){
            if let text = textField.text {
                
                    
                    let str = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).replacingOccurrences(of: "0", with: "")
                    if !str.isEmpty {
                        textField.text = "0" + str
                    } else {
                        textField.text = nil
                    }
               
                
            }
            return false
        }
        return true

Comment: What is `txtMobileNumber`?

Comment: At what line are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you create Enum, you can choice your textField type and make the extension properties for this field

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if cellType == .phone {
            guard var sanitizedText = textField.text else { return true }
           if !sanitizedText.isEmpty && !sanitizedText.hasPrefix("(0)") {
              sanitizedText.text = "(0)" + sanitizedText
           }
        }
}
```