# UitextFiled with first letter must 0 and format will be like (0) 1234 56789

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitextfield

I am using phone number texfield, now i am using this format for texfield (#) #### #####, now issue is that i want first character 0 as compulsary, like this (0) 1234 56789, so user enter whatever first character must be typed 0, its not duplicate quesion number format is different

here is my code but its not working

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var oldText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if oldText.count > 15 { return false }
    oldText = oldText.replacingOccurrences(of: "(0)", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    if !oldText.isEmpty {
        oldText = "(0)" + oldText
    }
    let newText = String(stride(from: 0, to: oldText.count, by: 3).map {
        let sIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: $0)
        let eIndex = oldText.index(sIndex, offsetBy: 3, limitedBy: oldText.endIndex) ?? oldText.endIndex
        return String(oldText[sIndex..<eIndex])
        }.joined(separator: " "))
    textField.text = newText
    return false
}
```

Comment: Kindly don't ask same question multiple times.

Comment: @PGDev Sir its not duplicate you can see that number format is different for this question

Comment: it is a duplicate, you need to modify the second part of the code so the split is done differently

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i need to change format in 4 and 5 degit so its not possible i want like this (0) 1234 56789

Comment: Yes I see that the format is different but the solution should be very similar to the one given in your previous question. Have you tried anything yourself to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this format `(#) #### #####` only two spaces are used. So you can insert space at a particular index without a for loop like this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var oldText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if oldText.count > 14 { return false }
    oldText = oldText.replacingOccurrences(of: "(0)", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    if !oldText.isEmpty {
        oldText = "(0)" + oldText
    }
    if oldText.count > 3 { 
        oldText.insert(" ", at: oldText.index(oldText.startIndex, offsetBy: 3))
    }
    if oldText.count > 8 {
        oldText.insert(" ", at: oldText.index(oldText.startIndex, offsetBy: 8))
    }
    textField.text = oldText
    return false
}
```

Comment: this is working fine, but when i try to erase text its not erasing after 4th character

Comment: @GovindRakholiya Check the updated answer.